# What are the numbers in an inequality called?

Tags: inequality, terminology

Summand is to addition what multiplicand is to multiplication, but what is the terminology for the quantities of an inequality, such as 1<4?

My best guess is simply "quantity" for both parts of the term or "antecedent" and "descendant" on the respective side of the sign.

Comment: Well, $+$ and $\times$ are operators, while $<$, $\leq$ and $=$ are relations. Not quite the same thing. As far as I know, there isn't a terminology used here. IMHO, such terms have their origin in pre-notation days, where a lot of mathematics was written in long hand. I don't find the words "summand" or "multiplicand" very useful, and the latter is unwieldy. (Also, in some case, you have to distinguish between left and right multiplicands - say in matrix multiplication, which is not commutative.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any accepted name, but how about **comparand** (a thing to be compared)?

Comment: Some times we just say "the left side" and "right side." But that's more common with equalities.

Comment: I am beginning to consider anterior and posterior comparand to distinguish the two.

Comment: @noumenal People will understand you better if you use LHS and RHS respectively, given that you don't have a chain of inequalities. In this case you could say "the LHS of the $n$-th inequality"...

Comment: @AlexR I would like to describe a mapping function that maps a set of inequalities (e.g. 1<4) to a ratio (e.g. 1/4).

Comment: @noumenal $1<4$ is not a set of inequalities^^ Maybe you should define it as a function of two expressions instead? This would then seem to be $$f(x,y) = \frac xy \qquad \text{where } x < y$$

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for the suggestion. You are confusing e.g. with i.e.^^ "The list of examples following e.g. should not be exhaustive" (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e.g.#cite_note-2)

Comment: @noumenal No, I know the difference between _id est_ and _exemplum gratias_ :P I was hinting at $1<4$ not being a set (but instead an inequality). A set of inequalities would be $\{1<4, 42 < \pi^2\}$ (not necessarily true) or $\{1<4\}$.

Comment: @AlexR I guessed wrong. Instead, syntactic ambiguity is at fault here: A fruit salad is a set of elements (e.g. banana).